# How much force would an explosive decompression really provide?

Tags: pressure, rocket-science

In science fiction, explosive decompression is occasionally used to slow down or provide a nudge for very large spacecraft (for instance, recently in the 2015 movie *The Martian*, and in [this old Star Trek episode](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Cause_and_Effect_(episode))). It seems like the mass of the air in a spacecraft would be quite small in comparison to the spacecraft itself. Would such an event really be enough to substantially change the velocity vector of a spacecraft?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do a back of the envelope: At normal pressure the air has a density of approx. $1.2kg/m^3$ and it would escape at roughly the speed of sound i.e. $340m/s$. The interior volume of the ISS is approx. $900m^3$, i.e. the total momentum of the escaping air would be

$1.2kg/m^3\times 900m^3\times340m/s\approx 370,000kgm/s$.

The mass of the ISS is roughly 420,000kg, i.e. the delta-v would be slightly less than $1m/s$. That is so not worth blowing that hatch for...

Comment: I'm curious why we know the air would escape at the speed of sound?